# using v-if to use different route-links in header cause route to wrong path

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I am new to JavaScript Frameworks(although I used vanilla js or jquery(a little)) and I started with VueJS for my project.

I am writing a single page application that uses an restful-api as server.

I wanted that in header some links will appear if user is not logged-in(register, login) and disappear once logged in. And, of course, different set of links will appear.

a bit visualization :)
before login

HEADER => | Register(to='/register') Login(to='login')

after a successful login

HEADER => | Home(to='/') Profile(to='/profile') SomeOtherLink(to='/someOtherPath')

but sometimes, after login, although header is rendered correctly(I look in inspect and links were correct), It goes wrong pathes.
Such as first link before login was register and first link after login is home. When I clik home it goes to register. It is same for Profile and login. when I click profile it goes to /login. But third one works.

It seems somehow renders (not) wrong eventListener for links.

Here is my template.

```
...
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <template v-if="loggedIn">

                    <router-link :to="{name: 'Home'}"
                                 tag="li"
                                 class="nav-item"
                                 active-class="active">
                        <a class="nav-link"> Home </a>
                    </router-link>


                    <router-link to="/profile"
                                 tag="li"
                                 class="nav-item"
                                 active-class="active">
                        <a class="nav-link"> Profile </a>
                    </router-link>

                    <router-link :to="{name: 'SomeRoute'}"
                                 tag="li"
                                 class="nav-item"
                                 active-class="active">
                        <a class="nav-link"> SomeLink </a>
                    </router-link>

                </template>
                <template v-else>
                    <router-link :to="{name: 'Register'}"
                                 tag="li"
                                 class="nav-item"
                                 id="register-link"
                                 active-class="active">
                        <a class="nav-link"> Kayıt Ol! </a>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link
                            :to="{name: 'Login'}"
                            tag="li"
                            class="nav-item"
                            id="login-link"
                            active-class="active">
                        <a class="nav-link"> Giriş Yap </a>
                    </router-link>
                </template>
            </ul>
...
```

here loggedIn is computed property which is set true if user logs in, and false vice versa. It works correctly.

I tried using div instead of template tag but result was same.
How can I fix this? 
Am I in wrong place? Or is it a bug?

Comment: The error is somewhere where loggedIn is defined. Also this is the wrong usage of template tag.

Comment: How do I separate these links? I am an only beginner on html. I learned there is such a tag  a couple of days ago :d Is there a common way to group such links(without div, div breaks design) I checked loggedIn, and it set correctly the variable. It is computed property as I said

Comment: In regular html template is a tag that is not displayed, it is used for dynamic rendering with JavaScript, in vue template is a tag for defining markup of a single-file .vue component. To separate those links you can use anything and then style it with css to suit your design. I would suggest li tags since you already wrapped everyting in ul.

Comment: I removed template and add v-if one by one to each route-link. Result is same nothing changed.

Comment: As i said the error is not in the markup, it is somwhere where loggedIn is defined. Markup was just wrong so i pointed that out also.

Comment: Debug the `loggedIn` variable, maybe printing it, as @НикитаГулис said, the markup is correct, the problem is the variable

Answer (score 0):

I printed loggedIn and it was correct as I mentioned before.

Problem was not that though, Component rendered correctly. Problem was the click event listener I suppose.

**Adding unique key to each route-link solved problem**.

Most probably vue create an event-listener for each link, and once old links are destroyed and new links are rendered, it creates new listeners for new link but not remove old ones. Since there was no identity in links, it maps according to order. 
Once old link is replaced with new one, it has two listener, one for old link that stayed in the same place, one for intended for the link. So it triggers one of them when clicked.
Actually it explains that why it works as intended first, after refresh works wrong, after another refresh again works correctly.

I'm not sure if it is a bug or not, but adding key is the only and true solution as it seems.